# Injective Homomorphism Between a Group and its Permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've got the following two-part question. I fiddled with it for a while, but didn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

> Let $G$ be a group, and $g \in G$. Denote by $R_g: G\to G$ the map $R_g(x) = xg$. Prove that $\phi'G\to S_G$ given by $\phi'(g) = R_{g^{-1}}$ is an injective homomorphism. Explain what fails for $\phi'': G \to S_G$ where $\phi''(g) = R_g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi''(gh) = R_{gh}$ but $R_{g}(R_{h}(x)) = xhg $ which can be different from $xgh = R_{gh}(x)$ so in general $$R_{gh} \neq R_g \circ R_h \Rightarrow \phi''(gh) \neq \phi''(g) \cdot \phi''(h)$$ If you put $\phi''(g) = R_g$ you obtain an anti-homomorphism, not an homomorphism.

How to prove that $\phi' $ is an injective homomorphism ? See the following $$[\phi'(gh)](x) = R_{(gh)^{-1}}(x)= x(gh)^{-1} = (x h^{-1})g^{-1} = R_{g^{-1}}\circ R_{h^{-1}}(x) = [\phi'(g) \cdot  \phi'(h)] (x)$$

This is true for all $x$ so $$\phi'(gh) = \phi'(g) \cdot  \phi'(h) $$

and $\phi' $ is an homomorphism. For the injectivity, if   $\ \phi'(g) = 1$ then pick $x \neq 1 $,  we have $$\phi'(g)(x) = x \Rightarrow xg^{-1} = x \Rightarrow g = 1$$

so $\phi ' $ is injective

Comment: But how do you prove that $\phi'$ is an injective homomorphism?

Comment: @Newb: I have edited

Answer (score 2):

A group homomorphism is injective iff the kernel is trivial. But $g$ is in the kernel of $\phi^\prime$ if $R_{g^{-1}}=\operatorname{id}_G$, the identity permutation on $G$. So the right action by $g^{-1}$ must fix everything so...